# What is the opposite of precision?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

There is a variable in my code that I don't how to name. As its value increases, the precision (of some calculations) decreases. I feel like it would be misleading if I called it "precision" but I can't think of **the opposite**. For a moment I thought about **granularity** but I am not sure if that is better.

Comment: I guess you could call it ***imprecision*** (or ***inaccuracy***, ***uncertainty_factor***, etc.), but naming program variables is normally considered Off Topic for ELL.

Comment: Precision is a quality, and like any other quality there can be more or less of it. The specifics of a problem dictate what is precise or not. Things outside of a given range may be labeled imprecise, but even imprecise things have the quality of precision, though it may be of a very low order.

Comment: Would `uncertainty` work?

Comment: Perhaps **dispersion** is what you're looking for?

Comment: How about **precision loss**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps **looseness** would serve your purpose?

M-W [offers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/looseness?src=search-dict-hed) one of the following definitions for the adjective *loose*:

> 6 a : lacking in precision, exactness, or care
>      * *loose* brushwork
>      * *loose* usage

and also provides an associated noun:

> — looseness *noun*

This word has the advantage of being the same part of speech as *precision*, so it can be dropped right in as a substitute without requiring that your sentence be rewritten. So, for example, you could say:

> As the measurement's precision increases, its looseness decreases.
>
> As the measurement's looseness increases, its precision decreases.
>
> The precision of this component's manufacture is very high.
>
> The looseness of our current quality control procedure is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You might try "slack" or "fuzz".  They have a long tradition in programming history.  (And yes, variable naming is a somewhat esoteric little sub-dialect of English)

Answer (score 1):

What about **tolerance**?
High tolerance can mean low precision for measuring devices as explained in this link:

[Tolerance and Measurement Accuracy](https://www.keyence.com/ss/products/measure/measurement_library/basic/tolerance/)